# Css not supported in javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript for adding additional field like onclick the add button display the input field. For Example:

```
$(function () {
    var addDiv = $('#addinput');
    var i = $('#addinput p').size() + 1;

    $('#oeNew').live('click', function () {
        $('<p><tr style="background:none;"><td><input type="text" class="quantity ls_input4"  name="quantity[]" id="quantity' + i + '" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onblur="findTotal();"/></td><td><span id="place_units' + i + '"><input type="text" class="units ls_input4"  name="units[]" id="units' + i + '" readonly="readonly"/></span></td><td><span id="mrp' + i + '"><input type="text" class="mrp_rate ls_input2"  name="mrp_rate[]" id="mrp_rate' + i + '" readonly="readonly"/></span></td><td><span id="mrp_vlue' + i + '"><input type="text" class="mrp_value ls_input2"  name="mrp_value[]"  id="mrp_value' + i + '" readonly="readonly"/></span></td><td><span id="sale' + i + '"><input type="text" class="sale_rate ls_input2"  name="sale_rate[]" id="sale_rate' + i + '" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onblur="findTotal();"/></span></td><td><input type="text" class="total_amount ls_input2" name="total_amount[]" id="total_amount' + i + '" value="0" readonly="readonly"/></td><a href="#" id="remNew" style="text-decoration:none;">Remove</a> </tr></p>').appendTo(addDiv);
        i++;

        return false;
    });

    $('#remNew').live('click', function () {
        if (i > 1) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Html Code:

```
 <table class="table_sales_inner" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <div id="addinput">
        <p> 
        </p></div> 
       </table>
```

I write the  particular css for this table but that css not effect in the td's.

Comment: The markup in your string is invalid: you have at least one extra `<td>` open tag and are missing at least one `</td>` close tag.

Comment: Add link to fiddle with CSS code.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: sorry, I wanted to edit my comment, not delete that. Sure, </td> is optinal. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6

Comment: just i remove <td> after that it still have

Comment: @panther: That HTML is far from valid.  `tr` tags can only live inside a table, `td` tags must be direct children of `tr` tags, `a` tags cannot be children of `tr` tags, etc..

Comment: @panther, okay, I stand corrected, even HTML5 says `a td element’s end tag may be omitted if the td element is immediately followed by a td or th element, or if there is no more content in the parent element`. So, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Since jQuery 1.4 or so `$().live();` is not supported anymore.

replace: `$('#oeNew').live('click', f...`
with: `$('#oeNew').on('click', f...`

and replace: `$('#remNew').live('click', f...`
width: `$(document).on('click', '#remNew', f...`

and it should work like in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RYq4g/)

Comment: Deprecated in 1.7, removed in 1.9.

Comment: it's works actually i write the css for <td> borders and input field style, those are not working